# Exporting Very Large Database from mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Before I proceed, I would like to confirm can I export a very large table of `3.6GB` size using the MySQL Admin Export feature. I have exported tables of small size like 28 MB but just wondering exporting such a large database would break anything?

Say for example, in the image below, I want to export `category` table which is of 3.6GB size.

Also, I have more tables whose size is 11.6 GB for which I would like to do the export in the future.

I want to use this technique rather than using mysqldump.

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% (only ~99%) certain - but I think that MySQL Workbench uses mysqldump in the background. Think about Oracle XtraBackup by Percona if you're using InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't be anything broken , `mysqlworkbench` is a pretty mature software.
You just need to watch the filesystem of the storage where you are going to store the file.
`ntfs` would be fine, but `fat32` will limit you to around 4GB.

However, if you are just looking for an exporter with UI, Navicat Premium is more comfortable in my opinion. Hope it helps.